how to stop blue tooth app process and nfc service process or other name of process in system app in android 12 with java and flamingo?
I use android studio 2022.2.1 flamingo JDK 17 Gradle 8.7
blue tooth and nfc are off but i discover the system app named bluetooth app and nfc services app sometimes running even I manually stop the app process.
how to stop blue tooth app process and nfc service process or other name of process in system app in android 12 with java and flamingo and schedule running in background to stop these app process every 10 seconds?
I am new to android programming, Mainactivity.java show missing permission at code underline before compile
This view is not constrained.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>


update 1:
I made this app in android in usb debugging and still used this app when turn off developer mode but blue tooth and nfc app still enabled running sometimes by unknown thing. the app have activity cycle and have listener to check bluetooth status. will I minimize app that pause app , listener can not keep disable blue tooth? how to make it running background and keep listen bluetooth status? how to print trigger of bluetooth log by other app to my app text label? I want to find which app or which mobile network trigger it? is it call app trigger ? or 4G or phone network trigger?

I'm not sure why you would try and stop these services as they are designed to run all the time and get automatically restarted.
Also
<uses-permission> XML elements do not belong in a XML view file, they belong in the "AndroidManifest.xml" file only.
So you are using them in the wrong place.

got a pain feeling when blue tooth and nfc either one is running, sometimes it did not show running but still running , force stop disabled, some times enabled

I made this app in android but blue tooth and nfc app still enabled running sometimes by unknown thing. the app have activity cycle and have listener to check bluetooth status. will I minimize app that pause app , listener can not keep disable blue tooth? how to make it running background and keep listen bluetooth status? how to print trigger of bluetooth log by other app to my app text label? I want to find which app or which mobile network trigger it? is it call app trigger ? or 4G or phone network trigger?
